# How to access the XIB's owner?

Tags: objective-c, ios

The issue i am facing deals with multiple views, each needing to communicate with one another. I chose to use the File Owner for this, but can't seem to be able to access *the already loaded* instance of it from inside of views.

- Each rectangle represents its own view
- Activity will happen on "Some View", where user's event will cause Labels in top view to be updated
- Event will not be triggers by a button click of anything like that. No outputs are set up to establish relationships between the views

[image]

- No outlets are set up between the views
- Outlets are setup however between top Views (with Labels) and File Owner (UIViewController).

**Ultimately, i'd like to update label in view 1 from view 2.**

Then the bar moves, I want labels to change

[image]

At this time, i believe a reasonable solution would be to ask the File Owner to make a change for Labels. From the "Some View", i'd like to call the File Owner and make a request.

**From the stand point of the any view residing as part of the nib, how can i know who the "File Owner" of this nib is?**

In the Interface Builder, File Owner maintains the IBOutlet to UILabels of the view.
[image]

Comment: What outlets have you defined? It's not clear from your question where you expect the code snippet to be, within a view, or viewcontroller?

Comment: I'm still not sure _where_ you want to be updating the label from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a `delegate` (or whatever you like to call it) outlet in your Puzzle1 class and link this to File's owner in the nib. This will give you a pointer to the instance of the view controller that currently owns your view. If you set the type of the delegate to your viewcontroller subclass, then its methods and properties will be available to you from within the view.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds potentially horrendously messy and is probably better solved by using NSNotifications.

But anyways, did you know there's a UINib class?  Perhaps you could subclass that and keep track of the owners (which get passed in it's `instantiateWithOwner: options:` method) as things are loaded.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html